# empty output on brute force task

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a brute force task, but when I run my program, it gives an empty output file. Can anybody please help me fix this? The problem statement is below along with my code after that.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

Write a program that reads two numbers (expressed in base 10):
N (1 <= N <= 15)
S (0 < S < 10000)
and then finds and prints (in base 10) the first N numbers strictly greater than S that are palindromic when written in two or more number bases (2 <= base <= 10).
Solutions to this problem do not require manipulating integers larger than the standard 32 bits.

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string convert(int num, int base)
{
    int quo = 100000;
    int rem = 0;
    string to_reverse;
    while (quo > 0)
    {
        quo = num / base;
        rem = num % base;
        to_reverse += to_string(rem);
        num /= base;
    }
    reverse(to_reverse.begin(), to_reverse.end());
    return to_reverse;
}

bool is_pal(string conv_num)
{
    string reversed_conv_num = conv_num;
    reverse(reversed_conv_num.begin(), reversed_conv_num.end());
    if (reversed_conv_num == conv_num)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout("dualpal.out");
    ifstream fin("dualpal.in");
    int n, start;
    fin >> n >> start;
    vector<int> finals;
    int times = 0;
    for (int i = start + 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        if (times == n)
        {
            for (auto x : finals)
            {
                fout << x << "\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                if(is_pal(convert(i, j)) == true)
                {
                    times++;
                    finals.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What did you see your program do when you added cout/cerr logging? What happened when you stepped through in the debugger?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you print your results inside the loop and break. Why not print it after the loop, and use a proper looping condition?

Comment: Ah yes, USACO. For your purposes it should still work even though it does not show up. Try putting the file into the USACO portal and see if it works. Usually when I do it on Visual Studio, the text file is empty but it works in the USACO portal.

Comment: @Sharad Khanna it says program created empty file when I run in USACO

Comment: @AndyN. Put a breakpoint on `fout << x << "\n";` and see if that line is ever called.

Comment: If it's called the program will stop running and VS will come into the forefront and you'll be on that line.  If that doesn't happen and the program ends then you know `if (times == n)` is never true.

Comment: You output only `if (times == n)`. What if the else-part finds several pals and increments `times` more than once? Like going from `n - 1` to `n + 2`.

Comment: You could also just add a line like `std::cout << "I'm in if (times == n)":` and if that never comes up in the console you'll know you didn't make it.

Comment: I tested it and it never reaches if (times == n)

Comment: @Andy N. for what values of N and Start are you trying?? Because I ran your code with N=2 and Start=10, and it works perfectly fine. You only have to add fout.close() before the main() function returns.

Comment: try with N = 3, start = 25

Comment: Output is added to the file but the output is "26 27 28". There must be a problem in the logic then. Sorry to say that. No problem in adding the output to the file. This is for N=3, start=25

Comment: for (vector<int>::iterator it = finals.begin(); it != finals.end(); ++it)
{
    fout << *it << "\n";
}   //try using this instead of for(auto x)...it might solve the problem...for auto didnt work for me

Comment: is it a direct issue with the way I am printing the answers?

Comment: @Andy N the output which is "26\n27\n28" is correct for N=3, start=25...I checked it by manually converting those numbers to different bases. And the output is also added to the file. Try opening the file in "ios::out" mode, if nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. I made some changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string convert(int num, int base)
{
    int quo = 100000;
    int rem = 0;
    string to_reverse;

    ostringstream str1;    /*this and the next commented lines are added because "to_string" didnt work in my compiler*/

    while (quo > 0)
    {
        quo = num / base;
        rem = num % base;
        str1 << rem;    //this
        to_reverse += str1.str();    //and this
        num /= base;
    }
    reverse(to_reverse.begin(), to_reverse.end());
    return to_reverse;
}

bool is_pal(string conv_num)
{
    string reversed_conv_num = conv_num;
    reverse(reversed_conv_num.begin(), reversed_conv_num.end());
    if (reversed_conv_num == conv_num)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("dualpal.out", ios::out);   //open the file in binary mode
    //ifstream fin("dualpal.in");
    int n, start;
    cin >> n >> start;
    vector<int> finals;
    int times = 0;
    for (int i = start + 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        if (times == n)
        {

            //just a simple iterator for vector
            for (vector<int>::iterator it = finals.begin(); it != finals.end(); ++it)
            {
                fout << *it << "\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                if(is_pal(convert(i, j)) == true)
                {
                    times++;
                    finals.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fout.close();   //close the file
    return 0;
}
```

**USE OF STRING STREAMS**

```
int number = 1000;
ostringstream s;
s << number;
string str = s.str();
```

This method can be used to convert number to strings.

This code requires `<sstream>` header file.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: a yes, it works, thank you so much! Just as a last note could you tell me more about what you changed and what I had wrong, so I can be ready for the next problems?  THanks

Comment: Sure. I added "fout.close()" because you have to close the file once you open it. Then I added an iterator for vector "finals" because "for(auto x)" didnt work in my compiler. Also, I changed used stringstreams instead of "to_string" method because it didnt work in my compiler.

Comment: @Andy N. I have explained in the answer how the String Streams work. I hope it helps :-)

Comment: If the answer helped you, do accept it as the correct answer so that it helps other viewers as well :-)

Comment: @Prakash Bansal I tried it but it said run time limit exceeded, it clearly isn't the case in visual studio because there it runs fine. Do you know why it is TLE on usaco grader?

Comment: @Andy N. I have never worked with usaco grader so I cant tell what causes the error.

Comment: that's okay, thanks anyway, I will look more into it.